# JQuery UI Autocomplete works but doesn't show any results

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I really need your help! Just spent about 3 hours trying to make that simple thing work, and looking at all the possible solutions on this site and others, and I cannot get it to work.

So I put an input field, assigned the correct script (copy/pasted from the jquery website). When I write something, it goes into the other PHP file, grabs the data, generates a JSON string, and returns it. This works perfectly fine and the JSON code is valid. However, the dropdown never shows up beside the input box.

I tried putting some extra CSS on my page, and with different Z-Index values, such as:

```
    <style>
        .ui-autocomplete {
            position:absolute;
            cursor:default;
            z-index:1001 !important;
            display:inline !important;
        }
        .ui-front {
            z-index: 1500 !important;
        }
    </style>
```

Using JQUERY UI 1.12.1 and CSS 1.12.1 with the Base theme.
Using Bootstrap 4.6.0
Check and they all load correctly

**This is my JS:**

```
    $( "#f_user" ).autocomplete({
        source: "scripts/list_users.php",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( "Selected: " + ui.item.value );
        }
    });
```

**This is my JSON response:**

```
    [{"label":"JESSICA, Robin","value":9048},{"label":"SICARD, Steven","value":9170},{"label":"SICARD, Steven","value":8580}]
```

And this is my HTML

```
    <div class="ui-widget input-group mb-1">
        <input class="form-control" name="f_user" id="f_user" placeholder="">
    </div>
```

I am not sure where to go next. There must be something on the page preventing the dropdown to show. I tried to Copy/Paste an example found online and it wasn't working. Any ideas?? Thanks!

Comment: Have your checked your browser's js console? Do you see any errors? Is the JSON returned from the PHP visible and correct in the `network` tab?

Comment: "*CSS 1.12.1 with Base theme*" - and did you select the autocomplete widget checkbox to make sure you get the CSS for that?  Have you used devtools to watch what happens when the autocomplete should display, can you see the elements appearing in the HTML?  Inspect them to see why they're not visible?

Comment: @AndreaOlivato and DOn't Panic: Thanks for your answers.  The Brower's console, does not show any errors. The JSON comes back correctly from the php script, in  network tab. I use the CDN for both jquery-ui.js and the CSS. I don't see any items appearing in my source code however I do see that jQuery adds the ui-autocomplete-input class to the input field. So It seems that JQuery does the request correctly, but it just does'nt show the dropdown...